# ADB "screenrecord" not working when executed form device

Tags: adb, screenshots

I recently found out about the [`screenrecord`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord) feature of `ADB` on Android since API19.

If I try and execute this from [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) on my device, I get the response from the device I would expect (identical to what I get on my CMD window when executing from Windows) but the file it creates does not work. The file is always ~3.3kb in size and VLC gives me the error:

`VLC can't recognize the input's format:
The format of 'file:///C:/Users/Jonny%20Wright/Downloads/videoo.mp4' cannot be detected. Have a look at the log for details.`

(I have not checked the VLC log as from what has been happening it seems it is a problem with the recording of the video by the device as when executing from Windows it works fine.)

Answer (score -1):

You need to run `screenrecord` as root, type `su` to switch to root (your phone needs to be rooted obviously)